# Edge Loop Select only shows one vertex highlight

Tags: interface

2.93.5

When in edit, edge mode I select an edge loop. the whole loop should highlight. However only 1 vertex highlight. Yes, the loop is active I can move it but it's just not lit.

[image]

[image]

Comment: make sure you don't have vertices overlapping, for example you can select all and M > Merge by Distance

Comment: Moonboots, Nope not it but thanks

Comment: or maybe you have an inner face? If it's still not the case, please share your file

Comment: This happens on a newly added sphere or anything so not geo issue. BTW how do I upload a .blend

Comment: Use https://pasteall.org/blend/ ... share the link it will give you in the URL field

Comment: New observation. I can see loop and vert selections.

Answer (score 1):

Got it,

I had set the Edge Select to black under themes. Doh! Thank all for the help
[image]